# Python Selenium: How to pull a link from an element with no href

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to iterate through a series of car listings and return the links to the individual CarFax and Experian Autocheck documents for each listing.

[Page I am trying to pull the links from](https://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/ferrari/458-spider/beverly-hills-ca-90210?dma=&searchRadius=0&location=&isNewSearch=true&marketExtension=include&showAccelerateBanner=false&sortBy=relevance&numRecords=100)

The XPATH for the one constant parent element across all child elements I am looking for is:

`.//div[@class="display-inline-block align-self-start"]/div[1]`

I initially tried to simply extract the `href` attribute from the child `<div>` and `<a>` tags at this XPATH: `.//div[@class="display-inline-block align-self-start"]/div[1]/a[1]`

This works great for some of the listings but does not work for others that do not have an `<a>` tag and instead include a `<span>` tag with an inline text link using text element `"Get AutoCheck Vehicle History"`.

That link functions correctly on the page, but there is no `href` attribute or any link I can find attached to the element in the page and I do not know how to scrape it with Selenium. Any advice would be appreciated as I am new to Python and Selenium.

For reference, here is the code I was using to scrape through the page (this eventually returns an `IndexError` as only some of the iterations of elements on the list have the `<a>` tag and the final amount does not match the total amount of listings on the page indicated by `len(name)`

```
s = Service('/Users/admin/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("https://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/ferrari/458-spider/beverly-hills-ca-90210?dma=&searchRadius=0&location=&isNewSearch=true&marketExtension=include&showAccelerateBanner=false&sortBy=relevance&numRecords=100")

nameList = []
autoCheckList = []

name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/h2[@class="text-bold text-size-400 text-size-sm-500 link-unstyled"]')
autoCheck = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="display-inline-block align-self-start"]/div[1]/a[1]')


for i in range(len(name)):
    nameList.append(name[i].text)
    autoCheckList.append(autoCheck[i].get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution. If it is a blocker for your current test automation progress, you can click on that link > switch to window handle (1) > copy the URL > close the current window > switch back to the default window handle